# Finalizing a Cursor that has not been deactivated or closed and no such table listitem in sqlite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I've been getting this error ever since i added a new table to my database, don't know why. I've done this methos a few time and there were no errors encountered but now this happens, sqlite are like women you do something for the first time and everything seems ok but when you do the same thing again they just start to get crazy for some reason.

anyway here's some relevant code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.selectorcreatemove);

        allFunctions();

    }

    private void allFunctions() {
        addMove = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAddMove);
        etAddMove = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMoveName);

        MoveList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMoveItems);
        SQLHandlerview = new SQLHandler(this);

        SQLHandlerview = new SQLHandler(ListMovingNames.this);
        SQLHandlerview.open();

        cursor = SQLHandlerview.getMove();
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        String[] from = new String[]{SQLHandler.KEY_MOVENAME};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text};

        SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);
        MoveList.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

        addMove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        MoveList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, final View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                AlertDialog load = new AlertDialog.Builder(ListMovingNames.this).show();
                load.setContentView(R.layout.load);
                move = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StartMoving.class);
                i.putExtra("moveName", move);
                startActivity(i);               
            }
        });

        etAddMove.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if ( (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN  ) && (keyCode== KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)   )
                {               
                    String ssmoveName = etAddMove.getText().toString();
                    int x = ssmoveName.length() - 1;
                    if (ssmoveName.equals("") || Character.isWhitespace(ssmoveName.charAt(0)) || Character.isWhitespace(ssmoveName.charAt(x))) {
                        Toast.makeText(ListMovingNames.this, 
                                "Please enter a valid name! Avoid giving a blank name or white space at the beginning or end of the name", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{
                        try {
                            String scheck = SQLHandlerview.checkMove(ssmoveName);
                            if (scheck.equals(ssmoveName)) {
                                Toast.makeText(ListMovingNames.this, "Move name already exist please give a different name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } else{
                                AlertDialog load = new AlertDialog.Builder(ListMovingNames.this).show();
                                load.setContentView(R.layout.load);
                                SQLHandlerview.createMove(ssmoveName);
                                SQLHandlerview.createList();
                                SQLHandlerview.setTodo(ssmoveName);
                                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StartMoving.class);
                                i.putExtra("moveName", ssmoveName);
                                startActivity(i);
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            AlertDialog load = new AlertDialog.Builder(ListMovingNames.this).show();
                            load.setContentView(R.layout.load);
                            SQLHandlerview.createMove(ssmoveName);
                            SQLHandlerview.createList();
                            SQLHandlerview.setTodo(ssmoveName);
                            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StartMoving.class);
                            i.putExtra("moveName", ssmoveName);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        allFunctions();
        SQLHandlerview.open();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        if (SQLHandlerview != null) {
            SQLHandlerview.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
            // do something on back.

            Intent i = new Intent(ListMovingNames.this, MainActivity.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

and here's the sql handler

```
public class SQLHandler {

    public static final String KEY_MOVENAME = "movename";
    public static final String KEY_ID1 = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_ID5 = "_id";

    public static final String KEY_MOVEDATE = "movedate";
    public static final String KEY_TOTALMOVEWEIGHT = "totalmoveweight";
    public static final String KEY_TOTALITEM = "totalitem";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mymovingfriend";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String KEY_LISTITEMNAME = "listitemname";
    public static final String KEY_LISTITEMWEIGHT = "listitemweight";
    public static final String KEY_LISTITEMROOM = "listitemroom";

    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE1 = "movingname";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE5 = "lisitem";

    public static final String CREATE_TABLE_1 = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE1 + " (" + 
            KEY_ID1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + 
            KEY_MOVEDATE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
            KEY_TOTALMOVEWEIGHT + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
            KEY_TOTALITEM + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_MOVENAME + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

    public static final String CREATE_TABLE_5 = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE5 + " (" + 
            KEY_ID5 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + 
            KEY_LISTITEMNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
            KEY_LISTITEMWEIGHT + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_LISTITEMROOM + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

    private DbHelper ourHelper;
    private final Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_1);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_5);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldversion, int newversion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE1);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE5);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public SQLHandler(Context c){
        ourContext = c;
    }

    public SQLHandler open() throws SQLException{
        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close(){
        ourDatabase.close();
        ourHelper.close();
    }

    public long createMove(String smovename){
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_MOVENAME, smovename);
        cv.put(KEY_MOVEDATE, "Not yet set");
        cv.put(KEY_TOTALMOVEWEIGHT, "0");
        cv.put(KEY_TOTALITEM, 0);
        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE1, null, cv);
    }

    public void createList(){
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        String[] sroom = new String[]{"Kitchen", "Bedroom", "Dinning Room"};
        String[] sitem = new String[]{"Dishwasher", "Bed", "Table"};
        String[] sweight = new String[]{"40", "25", "15"};

        for (int i = 0; i < sroom.length; i++) {
            cv.put(KEY_LISTITEMROOM, sroom[i]);
            cv.put(KEY_LISTITEMNAME, sitem[i]);
            cv.put(KEY_LISTITEMWEIGHT, sweight[i]);
            ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE5, null, cv);
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getitems(){
        String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID5, KEY_ITEMNAME};
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE5, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
            items.add(c.getString(1));
        }

        return items;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getitemweight(){
        String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID5, KEY_ITEMWEIGHT};
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE5, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
            items.add(c.getString(1));
        }

        return items;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getitemclass(){
        String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID5, KEY_LISTITEMROOM};
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE5, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
            items.add(c.getString(1));
        }

        return items;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

This value is still equal to 1.  I'm assuming that is the value you used when the database was created.  onCreate() is only called the first time that DbHelper is called on the device.  onUpgrade won't be called unless the value of DATABASE_VERSION is changed.  This means that your new table was never actually created in the database.

Try setting DATABASE_VERSION = 2.

------EDIT-----

There appears to be a typo in the value of DATABASE_TABLE5.

private static final String DATABASE_TABLE5 = "lisitem";

----for loops will fail if query returns 0 results-----

use:

if(c.moveToFirst()){

```
do{
    items.add(c.getString(1);
    c.moveToNext();
}while(!c.isAfterLast());
```

}

Comment: Try uninstalling the app from the device or emulator before running again. That will remove the old version of the database and force onCreate() to be called.  Should help you narrow down whether the problem lies in onCreate or onUpgrade

Comment: I've already found that one, and I'm sure that's not the reason, the source of my problem seems to be a cursor not being closed, but I'm not sure which

Comment: you are creating a new cursor in each of your get()'s such as getItemClass().  Try calling c.close() before your return statement in each one.

Comment: well I closed all cursor the problem is that when 

`public Cursor getMove(){
  String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID1, KEY_MOVENAME};
  Cursor cursor = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE1, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
  cursor.close();
  return cursor;
 }`
it return an error saying that attempt to re-open an already closed object

Comment: it would be better to declare private Cursor c; where you declare private DbHelper ourHelper; then recycle it in your functions with c = ourDatabase.query(.....   don't close it in your functions.  Instead close it in your close() function before you close the database...  Also your for loops will cause an error if the cursor returns no results...  I will edit my answer with a solution for that.

Comment: i did your suggestions man, now I'm getting a `nullpoint exception unable to pause activity`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18264/discussion-between-jason-hessley-and-philip)